# How to distinguish classes with the same name defined in different Gems?

Tags: ruby

I have two gems pdf-reader and origami. Each gem has a module called `PDF`. When I call them in the following order,

```
# Importing first gem
requires 'pdf/reader'

# Second gem
requires origami
include Origami

PDF::Reader.new(dir) # (first gem)
PDF.read dir # (second gem) #>> undefined method 'read' for PDF:Module (NoMethodError)
```

the first gem has no problem, but when I get to the second one, I get a mistake alleging that `pdf` does not have the `read` method. But if I first import 'origami' and then 'pdf/reader', I get error:

```
PDF is not a module (TypeError)
```

Ruby gets confused on which gem I'm invoking.

How can I specify that I'm talking about the specific first or second gem?

Comment: You need a way to distinguish the two `PDF` modules. And that is not easy.

Comment: Can you give me an example/link of how to do it? At least I'll try.

Comment: Please read my comment above.

Comment: I reported an issue about this to Origami https://github.com/gdelugre/origami/issues/52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific example, the `include Origami` is unnecessary, I don't know why they added that example to their `README`.

```
require 'pdf/reader'
require 'origami'

PDF::Reader.new(dir) # (first gem)
Origami::PDF.read dir # (second gem)
```

Sometimes it may be possible to do something like:

```
require 'pdf/reader'

PDFReader = PDF::Reader

require 'origami'
include Origami

PDFReader.new(dir)
PDF.read(dir)
```

Comment: ´undefined method 'read' for PDF:Module (NoMethodError)´ Besides, it's exactly the same as the original code. Do you know any Ruby code (that are not gems) to count pages in a PDF?

Comment: It's not exactly the same, the first example skips `include Origami` and uses it directly via `Origami::PDF.read` and the second one creates a `PDFReader` constant that points to the `PDF::Reader`, but as I said, it may sometimes work, apparently not in this case. `Origami::PDF.read('document.pdf').pages.size` will give you the page count using Origami only.

Comment: Origami and pdf-reader are used to count the pages of a pdf that I know, but in some pdf origami fails then I use pdf-reader and it works, I use begin and rescue. But both gems are slow and of course it gives errors as I have already shown, so I prefer to count the pages without using gems but I have not found any example of how to do it. I mean, I want to use pure Ruby.